# how to display each course entered in while loop? C#

Tags: c#

I'm unsure how to display each course the user enters. As it stands only the last course entered gets displayed. What am I not thinking about?

```
while (quit != "0")
{
    //get user data
    Console.WriteLine("Enter course # {0}:", counter);
    course = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter grade value of 1-4 # {0}:", counter);
    grade = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter credit hours from 1-3 # {0}:",counter);
    creditHours = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());


    //calculate grade * creditHours and store in gradePoints
    gradePoints = grade * creditHours;

    //running total of credit hours and grades
    totalGradePoints += gradePoints;
    totalCreditHours += creditHours;

    Console.WriteLine("Press '0' to quit or any key to continue.");
    quit = Console.ReadLine();
    counter++;// adds one to counter

}//end while

// calculate gpa
double GPA = totalGradePoints / totalCreditHours;

//display course(s) credit hours and gpa
Console.WriteLine("Course(s): {0}", course);
Console.WriteLine("Credit hours: {0}",totalCreditHours);
Console.WriteLine("GPA: {0:n2}",GPA);
```

Comment: Step 1: store the course in a collection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move

```
 Console.WriteLine("Course(s): {0}", course);
```

inside of your `while` loop. You are only displaying it after the loop ends. So that's why you see the last course.

If you don't want to display them immediately, then store the courses into a collection and iterate over the collection after `while` loop and display them:

```
var courses = new List<string>();
while(...)
{
     ...
     course = Console.ReadLine();
     courses.Add(course);
     ...
}

foreach(var c in courses)
     Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Comment: or `Console.WriteLine("Course(s): {0}", String.Join(", ", courses.ToArray()));`

Answer (score 0):

You're setting variables inside a `while` loop, therefore that same variable gets overridden with each iteration of the loop.

Instead, try using a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object or an array, both of which can hold multiple values, and consider making a `class` for your data, since it's all associated:

```
class CourseData
{
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public nt CreditHours { get; set; }
    public int GradePoints { get { reutrn Grade * CreditHours; } }
}
```

Comment: I found this helpful but I dont have the rep to upvote so thanks.